# Find reason for slow Jupyter Lab cell execution time

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The cell execution time in JupyterLab increased suspiciously after moving from Python 3.9 to 3.10. Execution time varies, but even simplest cells like

```python
a = 1
```

sometimes need up to 3s to execute. Is there a way to log the background procedures to find the problem-causing reason?

I am on Windows 10 and in a corporate network.

This is my jupyterlab general log:

```
NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.341 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.346 ServerApp] jupyter_server_mathjax | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.347 ServerApp] jupyter_server_proxy | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.356 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.365 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:06.365 ServerApp] nbdime | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:08.633 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:08.633 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:08.633 ServerApp] voila.server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:08.671 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.399 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.593 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.595 ServerApp] jupyter_server_mathjax | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.630 ServerApp] jupyter_server_proxy | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.632 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\other_software\Winpython64-3.10.4.0\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.632 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\other_software\Winpython64-3.10.4.0\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.635 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.643 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.778 ServerApp] nbdime | extension was successfully loaded.
/panel-preview/ /panel-preview
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.779 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.787 ServerApp] voila.server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.788 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\user01\OneDrive\Documents\Python\notebooks
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.788 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.17.0 is running at:
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.789 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=3adeff1d08fbbd087926e7fb006f1ff52813a474dec012be
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.789 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=3adeff1d08fbbd087926e7fb006f1ff52813a474dec012be
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:09.789 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2022-07-28 08:24:09.835 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/other_software/Winpython64-3.10.4.0/WPy64-31040/settings/runtime/jpserver-17128-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=3adeff1d08fbbd087926e7fb006f1ff52813a474dec012be
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=3adeff1d08fbbd087926e7fb006f1ff52813a474dec012be
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:14.274 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 2022-07-28 08:24:15.639 ServerApp] Kernel started: 9b7a709a-1553-44d2-8180-3f8e5686d48a
[W 2022-07-28 08:24:17.343 ServerApp] Got events for closed stream <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x000001C0DFA03910>
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 19eec36d-a89b-4c88-ae5e-4a96ec9bb23f
[I 2022-07-28 08:26:14.940 ServerApp] Saving file at /Projects/test/test.ipynb
[I 2022-07-28 08:28:17.394 ServerApp] Saving file at /Projects/test/test.ipynb
[I 2022-07-28 08:39:06.710 ServerApp] Saving file at /Projects/test/test.ipynb
[I 2022-07-28 08:39:09.889 ServerApp] Kernel started: 15c66d7e-8d29-4405-b0b1-bd320ba05a87
C:\other_software\Winpython64-3.10.4.0\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\_future.py:591: RuntimeWarning: Proactor event loop does not implement add_reader family of methods required for zmq. Registering an additional selector thread for add_reader support via tornado. Use `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` to avoid this warning.
  self._get_loop()
[I 2022-07-28 08:47:54.620 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in /Projects/test
[I 2022-07-28 08:47:57.711 ServerApp] Kernel started: b66e839f-0ccc-49d2-a608-8611b10346f3
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 7064f22d-7c01-4966-bdb9-99cd4cc24dcf
```

Comment: Bumping this because I have the same problem. So disappointed to discover this hadn't been touched :(

Comment: Maybe `jupyter lab --debug` could help. Just discovered the command and had no time to check it yet.